# how to enable and disable paging from jquery dataTables on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Following is the code found in data table website in order to remove the paging.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false
    } );
} );
```

My question is how to **enable and disable paging on button click**.

as when i call DataTable function **second time** to same table. It shows **error** that data table is already initiated and im calling it second time.

Comment: simply recreate the dataTable using `destroy: true` and `paging: <new value>` - despite the suggestions / answers below the lack of a working fiddle tells its own story.

Comment: thanks , kindly post it answer i will accept it. other answers and either not working or from old libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply recreate the dataTable using destroy: true and paging:

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show only the first 10 rows of the table, but still be able to sort the whole table. But I also wanted the ability to click a link and show the whole table.

Here's what I did: (my table is "ka_ad")

First, turn on paging

```js
table_ad = $('#ka_ad').DataTable({ 
 paging: true,
});
```

Second (optional: I didn't want to display the datatable pagination links and element, so I hid them with css

```
#ka_ad_length{display: none;}
#ka_ad_paginate{display: none;}
```

Lastly, toggle the bPaginate setting (I have a button with an ID of "test"):

```js
$('#test').click( function () {
     //console.log(mytable.settings()[0]['oFeatures']['bPaginate'] ); 
   if(table_ad.settings()[0]['oFeatures']['bPaginate'] == false)
        {
              table_ad.settings()[0]['oFeatures']['bPaginate'] = true;
             $('#test').html('Show All Rows');
        }
   else
        {
              table_ad.settings()[0]['oFeatures']['bPaginate'] = false;
              $('#test').html('Show Fewer Rows');
        }
     table_ad.draw(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
var oTable;
 $(document).ready(function() {
   oTable =  $('#example').DataTable( {
        "paging":   false
    } );

       $('.btn').click( function () {
        oTable.paging= false;
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

} );
```

Comment: there is no paging method present in the new library. fnDraw is changed to draw().

Answer (score 0):

try this:(but i don't guarantee, because, i haven't tested)

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

// get settings object after table is initialized
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.paging = false;

$(".button").click(function(){
    oSettings.paging = !oSettings.paging;
});
```

https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16373/enable-disable-features-after-initializing-the-table

Comment: the example or function u have shown is from old api. The latest data tables provide settings() function but there is no paging available